# pip and python referring to different interpreters

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, pyenv

I know "multiple-versions-of-python-mess" is nothing new but my question is more specific. I'm learning how to use venv (and pyenv, etc.) and I've run into a strange situation.

I have a number of different versions of python installed (as one does). I use one of them, 3.9, to create a venv:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/bin/python3 -m venv ./venvpractice
```

Then I activate it:

```
cd venvpractice
$ source bin/activate
```

Here's where the "trouble" starts:

```
(venvpractice) $ which python
~/venvpractice/bin/python

(venvpractice) $ which python3
python3: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3

(venvpractice) $ which pip
pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip3

(venvpractice) $ which pip3
~/venvpractice/bin/pip3
```

Wouldn't you expect `pip` and `python` to match (i.e. be from the same place), and for `pip3` and `python3` to match as well? Why are they all jumbled up?

I know it's not the biggest deal. I should just be careful and make sure I call the correct one, say, when I do `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`. But I just want to understand what's going on under the hood. I feel like things are still mucked up. So many versions and aliases and symlinks and PATH variables in `/.zshrc`... And then there's `pyenv` with which I also experimented a bit...

Please help?!

Comment: You provide an example why it's good practice use `python -m pip ...`

Comment: However, I would also expect that activating a Python environment (`source .../bin/activate`) ensures that the Python executable points to the Python executable of that environment. What does the PATH environment variable look like after the environment is activated? Also: Try to take a look at bin/activate - it is a shell script and you may understand what is going on when looking at it.

Comment: @normanius `echo $PATH` within the environment returns: `~/venvpractice/bin:~/.pyenv/shims:~/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/python@2/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/sbin` 

I'm not proficient at shell scripts and it's bed time soon but I will take a look at the `activate` script tomorrow.

Thank you for taking a crack at my issue.

edit: I replaced /Users/[my username] with ~ for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`venv` will not `unalias` anything for you; if you have aliases, your shell interprets those before the `venv` stuff even gets a chance.

My simple recommendation would be to remove these aliases from your shell's startup files, or at least interactively `unalias` them temporarily.

If you need for there to be an alias, try something like

```
alias python3='env python3'
```

which should do the right thing both in a virtual environment and out of one (provided your `PATH` is moderately sane, and you have `/usr/local/bin/python3` pointing to `/usr/local/bin/python`).

(Though in other news, aliases are inferior to shell functions. For this simple case, mmmmaybe live with an alias.)

A slightly more elaborate function might look like

```
python () {
    case ${VIRTUAL_ENV-} in
      '') /usr/local/bin/python "$@" ;;
      *) command python "$@";;
    esac
}
```

But ultimately, if you are using `pyenv` anyway, probably just get out of its way and let it handle these things for you; it does that nicely and transparently.

Comment: I'm assuming Zsh is not too different from Bash in these details.